# What is `gsd-media-keys`?

Tags: linux, gnome, process-management

Partial results from `ps` on a Linux box is shown below:

```
   PPID     PID    PGID     SID TTY        TPGID STAT  COMMAND
      1    1138    1138    1138 ?             -1 Ss    /lib/systemd/systemd --user
   1138    1466    1466    1466 ?             -1 Ssl   /usr/libexec/gsd-media-keys
   1138    2218    1466    1466 ?             -1 SLl   /opt/google/chrome/chrome
   1138    9142    1466    1466 ?             -1 Sl    nautilus
```

I am curious what is this `gsd-media-keys` process, and why some (not all) UI based applications run in the same *process group* with it.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is a plugin of the Gnome Settings Daemon.
The readme file of the Gnome Settings Daemon media keys tell us:

> gnome-settings-daemon will send key press events from multimedia
> keys to applications that register their interest in those events.
> This allows the play/pause button to control an audio player that's
> not focused for example.

You can find a bit more of information in the readme file:

https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/media-keys/README.media-keys-API

Comment: Removed in gnome 42 https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/commit/7b1ff8df213fb9ae0314bebb21e7afd4ff0854f1

Comment: The link https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/master/plugins/media-keys/README.media-keys-API seem to be stale (+ no README file [here](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/tree/master/plugins/media-keys)) and there is nothing to fix the still very real real issue in `gdm` 43.0 on Archlinux.

Comment: @Cbhihe You can find an older README from an older version on Github: https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-settings-daemon/blob/GNOME_SETTINGS_DAEMON_3_38_2/plugins/media-keys/README.media-keys-API